# dhcpcd service disabled yet dhcp works

Tags: dhcp, manjaro

I am using Arch (Manjaro) with Gnome. My organisation recently switched to a DHCP server. So we all had to switch our computers from static to DHCP.

What I noticed is that the [`dhcpcd` service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd) is disabled and not running. However, my desktop is still able to obtain DHCP addresses, and connect. What other service could be providing this functionality and navigating DHCP addressing?

Comment: @jimmij, It's funny that it is not the second case. The IT guy came in and switched the computer to DHCP, and waited around for the network admin to register the MAC address with the server (or something like that). Then the desktop connected on its own. I thought of reading the Arch Wiki on the subject, just for information, and learned about the `dhcpcd` service. However, the `dhcpcd` service was never turned on in this machine. There is no mention in `journalctl` either. I thought Gnome was responsible in some way, but could not find anything through Google. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Network Manager is usually used.
It has it's own internal dhcp client and is not compatible with dhcpcd.

See [here from the ArchWiki about NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#DHCP_client) - Manjaro is based on ArchLinux.

To check if NetworkManager service is loaded:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager
```

To check the journal for dhcp entries:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager | grep dhcp
```

Comment: Yeah, it is the `NetworkManager`. I didn't read it's wiki carefully enough to realise it has it's own DHCP client. Turns out the IP my desktop thought was assigned to it was incorrect, as I got an angry email from the IT guys. Further digging revealed that running `dhclient` (after `dhclient -r` to release the current DHCP lease) obtained the correct IP address. Then I put that together with the option to change the DHCP client backend as instructed in the Arch Wiki you kindly linked to, and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The dhcpd service is what you would use if you wanted Your Computer to be the server handing out network addresses.
The dhclient is probably what is receiving details and configuring your interface, and is part of the Network Manager suite.

Your question is similar to asking "Why can I use Firefox to access websites when my computer does not have https/Apache/nginx installed and running?"

Comment: What!? NO! I asked about `dhcpcd`, not `dhcpd`. I understand the difference between DHCP server and client, similarly webserver and web browser, thank you very much. Turns out, that DHCP connection was a fluke, I still don't know why or how, but it's something on the server side. It turns out my organisation is using a DHCP server with more complex navigation than what the built-in DHCP client of `NetworkManager` can handle. I did not know that `NetworkManager` had a built-in DHCP client. I found that thanks to [Michael D's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475686/289779).